# SELECT count(*) then output empty or not empty with yes or no

Tags: sql, oracle

Find if SALES department has its locations in exactly the same cities as TRANSPORT department"(assume that an empty result means YES and any nonempty result means NO)

In my database got this table.

```
//DEPTLOC
DNAME      CITY
----------------
SALES     LONDON
TRANSPORT LONDON
TRANSPORT BOSTON
SCIENCE   BOSTON
```

Not sure how to write the query but at least i try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DEPTLOC WHERE 
     (DNAME='SALES' AND DNAME='TRANSPORT') AND
```

How should i write after the AND operator in sql in order to get output something like this

```
//Display
YES . (<--- LONDON , got SALES and TRANSPORT in same cities)
```

Comment: You query will currently not return rows - the condition is asking if `DNAME` (in the same row!) is equal to both `'SALES'` and `'TRANSPORT'`, which is obviously false.  You'll need to join the table to itself in some fashion.  What sort of result are you actually looking for?  A straight `YES`/`NO` result?  A count of matching cities, or what?

Comment: ya. a straight yes / no result. . hmm. any suggestion? thanks

Comment: If you need yes/no, then `COUNT(*)` is a red herring/unnecessary - you're just looking for the occurrence of _any_ row.  You want to use `WHERE EXISTS(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [decode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm)

```
SELECT Decode(Count(*), 0, 'No', 
                        'Yes') 
FROM   {rest of your query}
```

`DECODE` compares expr to each search value one by one. If expr is equal to a search, then Oracle Database returns the corresponding result. If no match is found, then Oracle returns default. If default is omitted, then Oracle returns null.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little bit ambiguous, but I now think that this is what is asked: Give 'YES' if for all cities where there is a SALES, there is also a TRANSPORT, and NO otherwise.

I believe this query should achieve this.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Cnt = 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS Answer FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM DUAL
     WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT * FROM DeptLoc dl
         WHERE dl.DName = 'SALES' AND NOT EXISTS
             (SELECT * FROM DeptLoc
              WHERE City = dl.City AND DName = 'TRANSPORT')));
```

Modified from SQL Fiddle by Raging Bull: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff7a8/1

Comment: but my answer have to straight display
YES / NO . the question i already stated at first line..

Comment: @user3553846 - Then do that application-layer side.  Although there are ways to transform this to give the indicated input, they make the query more involved.

Comment: your query is not working.
error shown up with missing keyword.
can you try paste at SQL fiddle then i try to understand from there? 
thanks

Comment: I fixed it. The case when must be ended with `END`

Comment: @popovitsj The reverse check is not done (if CITY has TRANSPORT but not SALES). Check this out - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ea88/1

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this is what you are after:

```
SELECT CITY,COUNT(*),CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>2 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS STATUS
FROM DEPTLOC WHERE 
(DNAME='SALES' OR DNAME='TRANSPORT') 
AND CITY='LONDON'
GROUP BY CITY
```

Result:

```
CITY    COUNT(*)    STATUS
LONDON  2           YES
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b2452/11).

**EXPLANATION:**

`STATUS` field will be `YES` only if it returns 2 rows for that city. .i.e., 1 for `Sales` and 1 for `Transport`.

Comment: Of course, if there are no overlaps at all, this will generate no rows at all, so `'NO'` will not be returned.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: That will happen when users search for the city whose `DNAME`s do not exist in the table. I am using **OR** to find atleast one record.

Comment: if the london have another SALES or TRANSPORT again.
then the count will become 3 and status not correct aredy.

Comment: @user3553846: Edited my answer. BTW, 2 represents the number of parameters you check like SALES and TRANSPORT. If you are going to filter the output with more parameters change the number as well.

Answer (score 0):

To pick up whether you have sales and transport you should use a self join.

By aliasing the DEPTLOC table as 'sales' and 'transport' and joining on the city name you will get a list of the city which have both sales & transport.

```
SELECT sales.CITY
FROM DEPTLOC sales 
INNER JOIN DEPTLOC transport ON sales.CITY = transport.CITY
WHERE sales.DNAME = 'SALES'
AND transport.DNAME = 'TRANSPORT'
```

To get a list of yes and no you can use the above as a sub-query and use a case statement. I have added the distinct clause to eliminate any duplicate entries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY, 
CASE WHEN salesandtransport.CITY IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END as DISPLAY
FROM DEPTLOC 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT sales.CITY AS CITY
FROM DEPTLOC sales 
INNER JOIN DEPTLOC transport ON sales.CITY = transport.CITY
WHERE sales.DNAME = 'SALES'
AND transport.DNAME = 'TRANSPORT') salesandtransport ON DEPTLOC.CITY = salesandtransport.CITY
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this problem.  The following uses `full outer join` to compare the two sets of cities.  The idea is that any non-matching city will produce a `NULL` value.  This is detecting by comparing `count(*)` to `count(xx.City)`:

```
select (case when count(*) = count(dls.City) and count(*) = count(dlt.City)
             then 'Yes'
             else 'No'
        end)
from DeptLoc dls full outer join
     DeptLoc dlt
     on dls.Dname = 'Sales' and dlt.Dname = 'Transport' and dls.City = dlt.City;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should group by CITY and output Cities where count of DEPTS is not equal to count of DEPTS you need (2 in this case):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
         EXISTS(SELECT CITY FROM DEPTLOC
                       WHERE DNAME IN('SALES','TRANSPORT')
                       GROUP BY CITY
                       HAVING COUNT(*)<>2
                )
          THEN 'NO'
          ELSE 'YES'
        END
FROM DUAL;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/80033/1)</kbd>

Comment: Nice button for SQL Fiddle demo. How did you create it? You could consider using a column alias for the case.... column. The heading is very long.

Comment: @JosephB Just press the EDIT link under my answer and you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

This simple query should work just fine for you:

```
SELECT CITY,'YES' FROM DEPTLOC 
   WHERE CITY IN(SELECT CITY FROM DEPTLOC WHERE DNAME='TRANSPORT') 
         AND DNAME ='LOCATION'
```

OUTPUT will have those cities those have both transport and location and look like:

```
LONDON   YES
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative. A FULL OUTER JOIN is made between the rows having DNAME as SALES and TRANSPORT. Their differences are found if there are any rows with CITY as NULL in the other set, as follows:

```
SELECT DECODE(COUNT(*), 0, 'YES', 'NO') Display
FROM
(
    SELECT s.DNAME as s_DNAME, s.CITY as s_CITY, t.DNAME as t_DNAME, t.CITY as t_CITY
    FROM
    (SELECT DNAME, CITY
    FROM DEPTLOC 
    WHERE DNAME = 'SALES') s
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT DNAME, CITY
    FROM DEPTLOC
    WHERE DNAME = 'TRANSPORT'
    ) t
    ON s.CITY = t.CITY
    WHERE s.CITY IS NULL OR t.CITY IS NULL
);
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd8b8/39)**.

The SQL Fiddle also contains a query to list the cities with only SALES or TRANSPORT.