# SELECT clause with MINUS INTERSECT and UNION

Tags: sql, oracle

In my database, i created a table name DEPTLOC

```
//DEPTLOC
DNAME               CITY
----------------------------
RESEARCH          BOSTON
  IT              PARIS
 SCIENCE          LONDON
RESEARCH          LONDON
 SALES            NEWYORK
RESEARCH          PARIS
RESEARCH          NEWYORK
MARKETING         NEWYORK
```

So i used the following query

```
SELECT CITY FROM DEPTLOC 
INTERSECT
(
 SELECT CITY FROM DEPTLOC WHERE DNAME='SALES'
 UNION 
 SELECT CITY FROM DEPTLOC WHERE DNAME='RESEARCH'
);
```

But my output is all the CITY will be displayed. My question is want find which of the DNAME='SALES' OR DNAME='RESEARCH' has its location in all cities.

So from the table above, all distinct city are

```
CITY
-------
BOSTON
PARIS
LONDON
NEWYORK
```

Since 'RESEARCH' have all the location but 'SALES' Only have some, my output should be display like this

```
DNAME
---------
RESEARCH
```

What should i change for my query in order to get the correct output

Comment: possible duplicate of [SELECT count(\*) then output empty or not empty with yes or no](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266936/select-count-then-output-empty-or-not-empty-with-yes-or-no)

Comment: but hope to do with algebra operation .
yes. i know how to do using the count(*) if any DNAME count city is equal to the count(*) from DEPTLOC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shorter (than my previous answer) query that checks only between DNAMES SALES and RESEARCH to see which DNAME has all CITIES. Set operators UNION ALL and MINUS are used.

```
SELECT DNAME 
FROM
(
  SELECT 'SALES' DNAME, COUNT(*) MISSING_CITIES
  FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM DEPTLOC
      MINUS
    SELECT CITY FROM DEPTLOC WHERE DNAME = 'SALES'
  )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'RESEARCH', COUNT(*) FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM DEPTLOC
      MINUS
    SELECT CITY FROM DEPTLOC WHERE DNAME = 'RESEARCH'
  )
)
WHERE MISSING_CITIES = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to count the distinct locations, and join it on the departments query:

```
SELECT dname
FROM   (SELECT   dname, COUNT(*) AS dept_city_count
        FROM     deptloc
        GROUP BY dname) d
JOIN   (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT city) AS city_count
        FROM   deptloc) ON city_count = dept_cirt_count
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query using joins. First all Cities are selected. Then, a `CROSS JOIN` is made between all Departments and all Cities. Then, a LEFT JOIN is made to select Departments that do not have all Cities. Then, another LEFT JOIN is made to select Departments that do have all Cities.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  DL.DNAME
FROM
  DEPTLOC DL
LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT 
      ALL_COMBOS.DNAME dname
    FROM
      (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          D1.DNAME DNAME,
          D2.CITY CITY
        FROM
          DEPTLOC D1
        CROSS JOIN
          (
            SELECT DISTINCT
              CITY
            FROM
              DEPTLOC
          )
          D2 --All distinct Cities
      )
      ALL_COMBOS --All Departments with all Locations
    LEFT JOIN DEPTLOC D2
    ON
      ALL_COMBOS.DNAME  = D2.DNAME
    AND ALL_COMBOS.CITY = D2.CITY
    WHERE
      D2.DNAME IS NULL
  )
  NOT_ALL_LOCATIONS --Departments that do not have all Locations
  ON DL.DNAME = NOT_ALL_LOCATIONS.DNAME
WHERE
  NOT_ALL_LOCATIONS.DNAME IS NULL; --Departments that have all Locations
```

As it can be observed, this method does not rely on the count of the Cities, but on the actual values of the Cities themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the key in deptloc is (dname, city) then the following would work:

```
select dname
  from deptloc
 group by dname
 having count(*) = (select count(distinct city) from deptloc);
```

The query works by creating one group for every department. The count(*) would be the nr of cities that the department is located in. Each such count is compared with the nr of unique Cities cited in the same table.

**Edited**: Saw your comment now, that this was the solution you did not want :)

Here is another version of "relational division"

```
select departments.dname 
  from (select distinct dname from deptloc) departments
 where not exists(
   select 'x'
     from (select distinct city from deptloc) cities
    where not exists(
      select 'x'
        from deptloc x
       where x.city  = cities.city
         and x.dname = departments.dname));
```